# Pascals Triangle using one dimensional array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to make pascals triangle with just one, one dimensional array. I have some code here that I have been working with but it gets stuck. Thanks in advance. If you need the rest of the program please let me know and ill post it.

```
int fillArray(int triArray[], int arrSize)
{
    int last = 1;
    int current = 3;
    int flag = 0;

    for (int x = current; x < arrSize; x++)
    {
        if (triArray[last] == 1 && flag == 0)
        {
            triArray[current] = 1;
            current++;
            last++;
            flag++;

            cout << triArray[x] << " ";

        }

        triArray[current] = triArray[last] + triArray[last - 1];
        current++;

        cout << triArray[x] << " ";

        if (triArray[last] == 1)
        {
            triArray[current] = 1;
            flag = 0;
            current++;
            last++;

            cout << triArray[x] << endl;
        }


    }

    return *triArray;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "it gets stuck"?  Do you have a deadlock?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by deadlock, but it gets stuck on the number 3, like it goes through fine 1,11,121, then it messes up and puts 21333 and then repeats the 3 for the rest of the array size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of creating each row in turn, and storing them sequentially in your linear array. Build up some abstraction over the linear array to be able to access by row and column. Otherwise you will just get all tangled up in the code (as you seem to be right now).

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am new here and don't know how to close a question I asked myself haha. I figured it out last night at 2AM and just used one array and then lastOrder, currentOrder and an add variable and figured out that in each sequence you just increase the adder by 1 and then put a 1 at the beginning and end. But thank you very much for answering!